# Postfix/Dovecot - Mail not delivered

Tags: email, debian, postfix-mta, dovecot

I've setup a mail server using postfix and dovecot. Things look mostly ok in that:
- my server (a VPS) has MX records set correctly and resolving
- authentication via dovecot for SMTP and IMAP works ok (Thunderbid can connect to both for sending and receiving email)
- mail is sent correctly when using mThunderbird to external addresses (like yahoo)

Tutorial follows initially:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-set-up-a-postfix-e-mail-server-with-dovecot

Problem is that incoming mail never shows in the IMAP folders managed by dovecot. Mail logs say that incoming mail was delivered but when I use netcat to login and browser IMAP folders, they are always empty.

I noticed a few online sites saying that postfix might be unable to relay the mail to dovecot. I am not sure how the communication between them should take place and especially how it should be configured.

Can somebody please help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to check IMAP INBOX folder accessing it via IMAP protocol?

As I understand new messages are delivered to default mailbox file [/var/mail/UserName] and dovecot treats it at INBOX IMAP folder.

Relevant dovecot configuration part:

```
 mail_location = mbox:~/mail:INBOX=/var/mail/%u
```

Comment: I tried to check IMAP inbox manually via telnet and it shows me empty folders (even though there should be mail in the inbox). In my case, I am using Maildir format (specified in both configurations both for postfix and dovecot). Is there a way to specify mailbox location in postfix configuration to make sure they are on the same path?

Comment: Standard check: Have you restarted dovecot after changing its configuration? [Sorry but "no restart/reload" gives ~10% hit rate based on my experience]

Comment: yes, I've restarted (always restart both postfix and dovecot) changes that I make seem to be taken into account every time.

Comment: Are the messages delivered to /var/mail/UserName mailbox file?

Comment: actually the mailbox created by postfix is at /home/username/Maildir  while dovecot seems to use /home/username/mail/Maildir

Comment: If your postfix uses `home_mailbox = Maildir/` then make dovecot use `mail_location = maildir:~/Maildir`.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PostfixBasicSetupHowto#Setting_Postfix_Support_for_Maildir-style_Mailboxes  http://wiki2.dovecot.org/MailLocation/Maildir